# Should Ubuntu 22.04 ZFS with encryption also encrypt the data partion?

Tags: partitioning, encryption, 22.04, luks

I did a clean install of ubuntu 22.04 and I choose ZFS with encryption.
Now when I check the partitions, I see that only the EFI and SWAP partitions are encrypted and my data partition is not. Is this expected? is there anything else I am missing?

[Image of GParted showing the partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ugjjq.png)

[Image of lsblk showing the partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PrCW.png)

I am not new to linux, but I am new to LUKS. I want the full disk and data to be encrypted due to work data. Can I add the data partition to be encrypted? Do I have to reinstall?

EDIT: I moved to LVM with encryption as it works better.

Comment: ZFS has some encryption integrated, so you will not see any luks partitions or the like wrapping these partitions.

Please note that ZFS only encrypts Data and not Metadata. For more in depth information you could refer to https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/06/a-quick-start-guide-to-openzfs-native-encryption/ (Chapter "What’s encrypted—and what isn’t?")

Answer (score 1):

When you set up full disk encryption during installation, it only encrypts your system installation.

If you choose to keep a separate data partition, it will not be encrypted by the installer. You will need to set up encryption for that partition.

You can format a new LUKS encrypted partition using the Disks application.

Comment: I did not try to have a different partition, I gave the installer my entire drive (i deleted all partitions). I think the entire OS is installed into the nvme0n1p4 and therefore nothing is encrypted besides the swap and boot partition. I am not sure what nvme0n1p3 is or why it was created (as its not labeled).

Comment: The behavior you are describing is not consistent with the default installation options. Did you use the guided install or "something else"?  If you want everything on one partition, format the disk and start over, choosing the default installation options.

Comment: I reinstalled and it looks like the problem persisted or it doesnt show corectly. Maybe is just my bad understanding of ZFS so I moved to LVM with encryption and it works better.